# Upload a Flash file to server in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, vb.net, file, upload

I want to provide an option to upload a flash file onto my server for my customers. I am using ASP.NET MVC with VB.

I am looking for code  with in controller to upload file to my server and rename it, and the necessary security measures I need to consider.

Any pointers to a reference is fine.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you have some examples which will help you

http://www.codegain.com/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=511:file-upload-in-aspnet-mvc-application&catid=76:mvc-framework&Itemid=139

http://aspzone.com/tech/asp-net-mvc-file-upload/

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/dhananjaycoder/Fileuploadinaspnetmvc06292009030526AM/Fileuploadinaspnetmvc.aspx

Happy coding!